# Home grown relying party and Office 365 relying party on same ADFS server, but are not sharing auth

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, adfs3.0

We have a home grown ASP.NET MVC portal where users log in using ADFS. This portal has an outgoing link to Office 365, which has a relying party trust set up on the same ADFS server. When authenticated users on the portal click on this O365 link they are presented a login page. Is there any way they can continue to Office 365 without having to sign in the second time?

Comment: Is O365 a federated domain? Are you using IWA?

Comment: O365 is federated. Not sure about IWA. did you mean OWA?

Comment: just checked with admin. we are not using IWA. O365 is federated.

Comment: By IWA, I mean Integrated Windows Auth. which allows SSO.

Comment: @nzpcmad O365 is federated and we're not using IWA.